# NetBeans IDE java program not retrieving directory correctly

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, java-io, jfilechooser

I'm writing a program in Java (IDE: NetBeans 7.4, JDK 7, Swing API) to substitute Microsoft's crappy Notepad.

The problem I'm facing is, I have added a button to fetch directory where the user wishes to save the file. Here's the code for the button (named choosedir):

```
private void choosedirActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
  int select=choose.showOpenDialog(this);
  if (select == choose.APPROVE_OPTION){
   String dir=choose.getName(choose.getCurrentDirectory());
   directory.setText(dir.toString()+"-");
  }
}
```

The above code sets the chosen directory in the text box "directory".

Now, the code for the writer:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
String dir=choose.getName(choose.getCurrentDirectory());
   directory.setText(dir.toString());
    File file=new File(dir+name+".txt");
   try{
       Writer out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file), "UTF8"));
   out.append(input.getText());
   }
   catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) 
   {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
   } 
   catch (IOException e) 
   {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
   } 
}
```

The problem is:
1. No file is being saved
2. Whatever directory I select, it shows the directory name as seen in Windows Explorer. Like, if i want it in C:/Windows/Temp, it shows only Temp. Or even for C:/, it shows "Local Disk C:.

**UPDATE 11/16/2013: Despite help from alex, the program still fails to work. Here's the entire source code:**

```
import java.io.*;
public class QuickPad_v1 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form QuickPad_v1
 */
public QuickPad_v1() {
    initComponents();
}
/* Avoid the non-programmed buttons below! */
private void extensionActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                         

private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                        

private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
  System.exit(0);
}                                        

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
String dir=directory.getText();
    File file=new File("C://"+name+".txt");
   try{
       Writer out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file), "UTF8"));
   out.append(input.getText());
   }
   catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) 
   {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
   } 
   catch (IOException e) 
   {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
   } 
}                                        

private void choosedirActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
  int select=choose.showOpenDialog(this);
  if (select==choose.APPROVE_OPTION){

    }
}                                         

public static void main(String args[]) {
 java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new QuickPad_v1().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Help needed please! I'll give you a vote, promise!

Answer (score 1):

Read more about using of [`JFileChooser`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) and [its methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html).

In your code you havent full path to file, for saving it where you want, because of that it saves... `file.getAbsoluteFile()` helps you to know where is it:

```
String dir=choose.getName(choose.getCurrentDirectory());
directory.setText(dir.toString());
File file=new File(dir+name+".txt");
```

Try next code it helps you:

```
String dir = choose.getCurrentDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
directory.setText(dir);
File file = new File(dir+ File.separator + name + ".txt");
```

Comment: Hi alex, still fails to work. Can you debug the source code above? Thanks!